# No scrollbar appears in container with overflow auto (IE10, Windows Phone 8)

Tags: css, windows-phone-8, scrollbar, internet-explorer-10

I have a container (let's say a `div`) with `overflow: auto`.

The elements in it are scrolled exactly as expected, but the typical touch scrollbar doesn't appear.

I tried to set `-ms-overflow-style: auto` explicitly, but nothing changed.

- **Browser: IE10**
- **Device Windows Phone 8**

Answer (score 1):

Check behavior here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh771902(v=vs.85).aspx

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the above link I think you should try

`-ms-overflow-style: scrollbar`

Scrollbar Indicates the element displays a classic scrollbar-type control when its content overflows.

Answer (score -4):

add: `overflow:scroll;` and it will show a scrollbar

Comment: hm, sorry, it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Adding overflow:scroll will permanently place scrollbar containers horizontally and vertically