# How to make scrollbar to appear when scrolling inside an element on Windows Phone?

Tags: css, windows-phone, scrollbar

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/9udv2o13/) is my code.

When scrolling the content inside the `div`, the scrollbar of the `div` correctly appear on iOS. However, the scrollbar does not appear on Windows Phone.

I had tried all of the CSS declarations listed at [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh771902%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16791444/no-scrollbar-appears-in-container-with-overflow-auto-ie10-windows-phone-8?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible with the current version of IE Mobile. Even with an explicit

```
overflow-y: scroll;
```

the scrollbar will not appear.

There are several JavaScript solutions which will work with Windows Phone too. I tried [JScrollPane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/) with my Nokia Lumia 1020 and the scrollbar is visible. They have some demo pages, i.e. http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/basic.html.

Another nice script is [slimScroll](http://rocha.la/jQuery-slimScroll). This jQuery plugin also gives you the possibility to hide the scrollbar when the div don't have the focus (`alwaysVisible: false`).